# How to provide types in the for.. in.. loop in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to provide type to the constant `property`

```
var object = {...Sample object};

for (const property in object) {
    console.log(property);
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: does it answer to your question? https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-iterate-easily-over-object-properties-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [for..in statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) states:

> The `for...in` statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.
>
> ```
> const object = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
>
> for (const property in object) {
>   console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
> }
>
> // expected output:
> // "a: 1"
> // "b: 2"
> // "c: 3"
> ```

Your `property` variable is inferred by TypeScript compiler to be a `string`. There is no need for type hints from the programmer.